# Center form content vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, vertical-alignment

I've got [the following landing page form](https://jsfiddle.net/0x9epxah/) (I've cut all the unnecessary stuff I don't think matters leaving only minimum of style). Here is the code (I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.5):

```
<div class="col-md-6 app-door">
  <form class="image-hover text-center">
    <h3>Application name</h3>
    <div class="landing-page-form-group">
      <label class="landing-page-label">Label: </label>
      <input class="form-control landing-page-input">
    </div>
    <button class="btn">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <div class="center-block app-link some-img"/>
</div>
```

..and css

```
.image-hover {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) !important;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  color: #cccccc;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.landing-page-form-group {
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}

.landing-page-label {
  width: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.landing-page-input {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.app-link {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.some-img {
  background-image: url("http://dl.hiapphere.com/data/icon/201511/HiAppHere_com_com.ludicside.mrsquare.png");
}
```

I want to center all the form inputs and etc vertically. I've tried such things as playing with position (relative on parent, absolute on child), vertical-align, top, maybe something else I don't remember right now as I spent lots of hours trying.

I'm not a great specialist in frontend development (I mean html/css) so I will be extremely happy to see understanding although the problem seems to be basic enough.

Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: Might be helpful to include a screenshot of how it looks now, even better if you can make a fiddle.

Comment: @Bemmu Please, see the first link under the `the following landing page form` text

Answer (score 2):

**updated**
 check the solution without flex demo [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/cc0Lbrbw/4/)

Try this

check demo **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/cc0Lbrbw/3/)**

add the following styles to your existing `.image-hover` class

CSS:

```
.image-hover {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center; 
}
```

Comment: I completely for forgot to mention I have to support IE 11. Is there is any other solution? I will update the answer

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich flex works well till IE11 check [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

Comment: That's just great! Thank you very much!

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich I have the updated the solution without flex. please check the updated demo link in answer

Comment: Wow, it works! Look very.. how better to say it.. majestically:)

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich Thank you very much.  I hope you have got your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest method would be to use

```
.image-hover {
    display: flex;
    align-items : center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

The `align-items` takes care of vertical centering, and `justify-contents`, the horizontal centering.

Comment: The other guy was the first, all that I could do is up your answer, thank you!

Comment: Ah, no problem. Anyway, here's the solution, @dmitry-senkovich — https://jsfiddle.net/0x9epxah/2/

Comment: But it seems to be a little bit broken o_0

Comment: Try this one?
https://jsfiddle.net/0x9epxah/4/

If the field is in the center, it covers the smiley face, just an observation.

Comment: that's interesting but the button needs to be placed below all the input groups

Comment: Not really, frankly saying. It divides header and button

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution: 
https://jsfiddle.net/0x9epxah/1/

add div .inner-form:

```
<div class="col-md-6 app-door">
  <form class="image-hover text-center">
    <div class="inner-form">
      <h3>Application name</h3>
      <div class="landing-page-form-group">
        <label class="landing-page-label">Label: </label>
        <input class="form-control landing-page-input">
      </div>
      <button class="btn">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="center-block app-link some-img"/>
</div>
```

and this css class:

```
.inner-form {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```